# perl - how do you extract all elements of an array except the last?

Tags: arrays, perl

I need to extract all elements in an array except the last and store them in a scalar for later use.
At first, I thought this would be possible using array slices, but it appears that you cannot count backwards.
For example:

```
my $foo = ($bar[0..-2]);
```

or

```
my $foo = ($bar[-2..0]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is starting to drive me insane, and I have been unable to find a solution elsewhere or by experimenting.
Oskar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`my $foo = join ',', @bar[0..$#bar-1];`

will concatenate (by comma) all elements of the array @bar except the last one into foo.

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 12):

```
my @foo = @bar;
pop @foo;
```

or

```
my @foo = @bar[ -@bar .. -2 ];
```

or if it's ok to change @bar, just

```
my @foo = splice( @bar, 0, -1 );
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i will remember the examples for later, they could come in handy

Comment: I think pop is a bit nicer than splice for removing the last element :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@foo = @bar[0 .. $#foo - 1];
```

If you want to create a head-scratcher:

```
my @x = (1, 2, 3);
print "@x[-@x .. -2]";
```

Answer (score 2):

This will store all array elements, except for the last, into a scalar. Each array element will be separated by a single space.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = 1 .. 6;
my $str = "@nums[0 .. $#nums - 1]";
print $str;

__END__

1 2 3 4 5
```

Don't you really want to store the elements into another array?  If you store them in a scalar, it can be problematic to retrieve them.  In my example above, if any element of the array already had a single space, you would not be able to properly reconstruct the array from the scalar.

Comment: thanks for the good reply but no I would like to store them as a scalar as i want to turn "forename initial(s) surname" into "surname, forename initial(s)" and have already extracted surname and added a comma to it, just couldn't get forename and initial(s).